# How to remove excerpt white spaces

Tags: excerpt

This is my code in wordpress archive:

```
mb_substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 236);
```

This echos:

```
                  NGÀY 1: HÀ NỘI – ĐÀ NẴNG         Chiều: khởi hành
```

In view code `NGÀY 1: HÀ NỘI – ĐÀ NẴNG         Chiều: khởi hành`

How do I remove white spaces

Comment: What happens when you change your function to just `the_excerpt();`. Does the white spaces disappear, or are they still there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove white space after you get the excerpt, then you can do as below.

First get the excerpt as

```
$excerpt = mb_substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, 236);
```

Then do a string replace for space as

```
echo str_replace(' ', '', $excerpt);
```

Comment: but my code create very ' '. it's not true '         ' you can view : http://www.danangtourdulich.com/tourdulichdanang/

Comment: Do you mean multiple spaces? Can you please test the above code?

Comment: true if 2 spaces, but  more 2 spaces it's replace remove one spaces `NẴNG         Chiều` 5 spaces => 4 spaces, not 1 spaces

Comment: You might be doing something else. You can check the function [str_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) which says "replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string".

Comment: in my post: i'm add image, icon => more white spaces in excerpt. it's white spaces not character. if have 5 spaces `echo str_replace(' ', '', $excerpt);` remove one spaces. i have 4 spaces :(

Comment: This worked for me. Had an issue with trying to use urlencode() on get_the_excerpt outputting a bunch of white space. Chittaranjan's solution did the trick.